# Modify file name using Python Script

Tags: linux, bash, python-2.7

I have many files in my folder with names `1.jpg-xyz`, `1.jpg-abc`, `2.jpg-qwe` etc. I particularly want to move  .jpg to the end of each image's name. I can't do it manually since these are thousands in number. I can't get rid of **xyz** etc after **.jpg** in the current name since they have important information. So only option I have is to shift **.jpg** to end. Can somebody tell me what command or script should I use to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
find *jpg* | while read f ; do g=$(echo "$f" | sed s/\.jpg//) ; echo "mv $f ${g}.jpg" ; done
```

If the mv commands echoed look like what you want then remove the echo "" around it and re-run.

Answer (score 0):

The below bash code will list all files with .jpg- and move them to -.jpg

```
re='([^.]+)\.jpg(-.*)'
for file in *.jpg-*
do
    if [[ $file =~ $re ]]
    then 
        mv $file "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}.jpg"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Why `for file in $(ls *.jpg-*)`? Why not `for file in *.jpg-*`?